# Recaptcha and external form post action?

Tags: php, recaptcha

I am trying to post an action to an external url using the php library for google's reCAPTCHA like so:

```
<?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php');

$publickey = "***";
$privatekey = "***";

$resp = null;
$error = null;

if ($_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]) {
        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                        $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                        $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
  } else {
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification
  }
}
?>
<form action="https://www.salesforce.com" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="oid" value="00DA0000000HSo1">
    <input type="hidden" name="00NG0000007s5J1" value="Contact Us">
    <input type="hidden" name="retURL" value="{siteurl}contact-thank-you.html">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="12%" align="right"><label for="first_name">First Name</label></td>
            <td width="210px"><input id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" class="inputbox" /></td>
            <td width="12%" align="right"><label for="last_name">Last Name</label></td>
            <td width="210px"><input id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" class="inputbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><label for="email">Email</label></td>
            <td><input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" class="inputbox" /></td>
            <td align="right"><label for="phone">Phone</label></td>
            <td><input  id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" class="inputbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><label for="company">Company</label></td>
            <td><input  id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" size="20" type="text" class="inputbox" /></td>
            <td align="right"><label for="URL">Website</label></td>
            <td><input  id="URL" maxlength="80" name="URL" size="20" type="text" class="inputbox" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
<?php
echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey, $error);
?>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="30"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input  id="00NA0000000Ujum" maxlength="255" name="00NA0000000Ujum" size="20" type="hidden" value="{referrer}" />
</form>
```

how do I go about validating the form using the reCaptcha using the same page and if correct 
send the user to the external action?
I'e also tried this:

```
<?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$publickey = "***";
$privatekey = "***";


$resp = null;

$error = null;

if ($_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]) {
        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                        $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                        $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

        if ($resp->is_valid) {
                $action = 'https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8';
        } else {

            echo $error;
                $error = $resp->error;
        }
}
?>
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="POST">

</form>
```

Comment: I'm curious about this also in terms of whether or not it's possible. The workaround would be to localize the form post to your site and use Salesforce API to send over the form data once recaptcha has been validated.